# select joins and group by in codeigniter

Tags: join, group-by, codeigniter-3

In Codeigniter3, I have the following select join model:

```
public function get_post()
{
    $q = $this->db->select('posts.id, posts.active, posts.title, posts.close_date, users.name')
    ->from('posts')
    ->join('users', 'posts.user_id = users.id', 'left')
    ->where('posts.active','1')
    ->where(['posts.active' => '1', 'posts.close_date  >=' => date('Y-m-d')])
    ->order_by('posts.updated_at', 'DESC')->get();
    return $q;
}
```

How can I list all posts with count posts for each user (count only posts where posts.active = 1 and posts.close_date >= current date)?

If CI can't do the job, please give me the sql query.

Comment: have you solved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

With complex queries like this, the best way is to store the sql script in a string variable and use [`$this->db->query()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=db%20query#CI_DB_driver::query) to execute it.

This query is in **MySQL**:

```
public function get_posts() {
    $sql = "
        SELECT `posts`.`id`, `posts`.`active`, `posts`.`title`, `posts`.`close_date`, users.name, COUNT(`posts`.`user_id`) AS `active_post_count`
        FROM `posts`
        LEFT JOIN `users` ON `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
        WHERE `posts`.`active` = ?
        AND `posts.close_date` >= ?
        ORDER BY `posts`.`updated_at` DESC;
    ";

    $now = new DateTime('now');
    $binds = [1, $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')];
    return $this->db->query($sql, $binds)->result_array();
}
```

Here's a sample code on how to access the post count:

```
$this->Your_model->get_posts()[0]['active_post_count'];
```

See CodeIgniter's docs on [Generating Query Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=result#CI_DB_result):

If you want the result as an object instead, use `result_object()` over `result_array()`.

Comment: Do I have to use $this->Your_model->get_posts()[0]['active_post_count']; in controller in order to access the model?